# Rails custom browser's tab title on send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I send `inline` pdf file with `send_data` (in a new tab)

```
send_data row_pdf_data, disposition: 'inline', filename: 'report.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
```

and I've got tab with PDF preview with a title with my action name (action which sends this data/file).
Sent Pdf document doesn't have title in the properties.
How can I send and use custom title on the new tab?

Maybe it's possible to send some headers in response or something to change the preview page's title

To be clear. I don't use WickedPDF, Prawn etc... This data/file comes from service and I can't change it on the fly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure it's the action name? I assume it is the file name.

Comment: @ChristianBruckmayer if I send file inline then there is action name, if I open pdf, then file name in title